# Belkin N150 Wireless Router (F9K1001) can't connect to Surfboard SB6141 modem

Tags: windows-8.1, wireless-router

I'm RMAing my newest router and had an old N150 laying around. I need the router so I can have multiple computers and more importantly for my broadband home phone. I know I used this router with the SB6141 modem before I bought the new router. However, I'm trying to connect it now and it won't work.

I can connect a PC directly to the SB6141 modem and it works fine. I can also connect directly to the N150 router and it seems okay too. I just can't get the router and modem to work together and therefore no phone.

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop if that helps. Not sure what difference that would make though since the modem and router can't see each other even with no PCs connected.

Thanks for any help,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this one. I followed the router setup procedure strictly, i.e. took out all other cables from the router, unplugged power from both, powered up modem and let it "settle", attached router to modem, powered up router and let it "settle". At first the router had the amber LED which means no connection, but after 10 seconds it went blue. Then I plugged in the LAN cables and everything works. Sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Belkin N150 and could not get it to setup and did a router firmware update on the router and then everything worked. Might want to check for router firmware updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log on to SB6141 Modem via laptop through Ethernet cable to modem port. Connect to 192.168.100.1
2. Go to configuration tab and click on reset to factory defaults button
3. Press reset/reboot modem button (upon doing so quickly disconnect cable modem port that was connected to your laptop and re-bridge the modem port to the router WAN port.
   ** The first device after factory defaults the modem need to pick up is your router, not your laptop.
4. reboot your router now and you should be back in business.